# Perforce linking files

Tags: java, perforce

I have two projects A and B.
I have file constants.java in A. I want to keep a mirror copy of it in B.such that when ever constants.java in A changes its automatically changes in B .
Is there any workout in Perforce.Help me out thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using streams or conventional workspaces?  Are the two projects using different workspaces?  You could definitely map the `constants.java` from one to the other, although I've not tried mapping a file twice in the same workspace.   For Streams, there's very good support for including read-only copies from other depots or streams.

Comment: Why do you want a "mirror copy"?  Why don't you just reference the same file in both projects?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this automatically with Perforce, but you could easily set up a cron job (or a build job if you have a CI system like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)) to use the [p4 integrate](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/integrate.html) command to merge any changes in A into B.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do this with a [change-commit trigger](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/chapter.scripting.html) that does the integration from A to B when A is submitted, but that seems like a terrible idea in general, and specifically because Perforce calls this out:

> When you use trigger scripts, remember that Perforce commands that
>   write data to the depot are dangerous and should be avoided. In
>   particular, do not run the p4 submit command from within a trigger
>   script.

Why not just have the projects both reference the same `constants.java` file?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something that works like SVN's `svn:externals`.

I think the closest you'll come with Perforce is using a symlink, which is a pretty poor substitute. You can check a symlink in to Perforce and it will understand the link. If you have

```
/root
   /project-A
      file1
   /project-B
      link-to-file1
```

and you want to work on project-B, you'll need to check out everything. Perforce isn't making the symlink transparent for you, it's just copying it around. It also might be a Unix-only feature.

Answer (score 0):

In perforce you define the setup of your workspace (aka client) via the clientview.
Each workspace/client has a list of mapping from depot-path to workspace-path. 
You can see/edit it by calling `p4 client`. 
For your situation you could simply add a mapping to the project-b client similar to this:

```
//depot/project-a/files/constant.java //project-b-client/files/constant.java
```

That's easy and you have what you are asking for.

BUT:
in practice if several people are working on project-a and project-b it leads to several problems:
 - in proper work environment everybody should have different workspaces/clients. Thus everybody needs to do this change. It's just a matter of time until somebody forgets it or does it wrong.
 - developers who have to use this, but are not very familiar with perforce will not think of the impact on the other project if they change "constant.java" in one of the projects.
 - imagine you want a codefreeze on one of the projects (for testing purposes for example). What if the other projects still wants to change "constant.java" ?

There are probably more hassles with this approach.
I rather recommend to either integrate the file from a to b and vice versa or (in a more complex environment) put the file (maybe it's not only a source file but also a jar or a bigger lib) into an artifact repository. Then projects get it from there (via a dependency manager). See [ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/) or [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) for example.

Those alternatives are certainly much more efforts but in a slightly complex software project they are definitly worth it.